# Internet explorer browser not submitting data correctly but ok in firefox and chrome

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, encoding

I have a JSP page that displays a field called a *company*, and this *company* field has the characters  "á é ó ú". I have a **company.jsp** page that displays the company name correctly on internet explorer browser.

However when the user clicks <kbd>submit</kbd> button from the **company.jsp** with debug mode enabled in eclipse, the field *company* is replaced with ????. Based on the online resources it looks like an encoding issue.

The following line is used to retrieve the company:

```
request.getParameter("companyName")
```

I have added the following config:

1. UTF-8 config - `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` this is added in the jsp page.
2. `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` - This is added to the methods that retrieves the company field.
3. Since I am using glassfish I have added   `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />` in the glassfish-web.xml file.
4. Internet Explorer encoding is UTF-8

The data is displayed correctly but the same data is submitted it is replaced by question marks on IE.

I am not sure how to solve the above issue any advice, please?

Comment: Specify a font that contains those symbols. Your ie default font doesn't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch are you sure having unsupported font would make the submitted data break  instead of just not rendering it properly?

Comment: @zack6849 Unsupported glyphs are rendered as `?` marks.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right, rendered, but i think OP is saying the data received from IE is question marks on the server side. Does it really just substitute the real character with a question mark if it can't render it? That sounds broken

Comment: IE  font is currently Latin based and text font Courier new,which one should i use instead?

Answer (score 0):

In fact it seems like it is a problem of encoding, but have you check if the company name is really in the request object after you submit?